# Loading a Cursor in Android with info from the MediaStore.Audio provider

Tags: java, android, cursor, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to load some parameters from the default Content Provider MediaStore.Audio into a Cursor but when debugging the code it stops running just in the managedQuery. The method just don't run further than the managedQuery. Here is the code with the query:

```
Uri exAudioUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

String[] projection = new String[] {
    MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media._COUNT,
};
Cursor cExAudio = managedQuery(exAudioUri, projection, null, null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + " DESC");
```

I've read in the documentation that this method is deprecated and shouldn't be used but is the only option I have with the API Level I'm using.

Comment: Please can you confirm whether it return managedQuery is returning null.

Comment: Just checked, during debug the managedQuery returns the following exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _count: , while compiling: SELECT _id, _display_name, _data, _count FROM audio ORDER BY _display_name DESC

Answer (score 0):

If you remove 
    `MediaStore.Audio.Media._COUNT` from `String[] projection` should solve your problem.

Basically there is no column called "_COUNT"

```
String[] projection = new String[] {
    MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
};
```